# Android default controls that is not in SDK

Tags: android, controls, scrollview

I have started to work with Android 2.3.3 and now have a few questions about its controls.

In default android there is a list of application icons, that can be viewed by pages (scroll as normal, but stop only on specified positions).

Also there is a control in default clock application that allow to select minutes and seconds by sliding it up or down by fingers.

Where can I find these controls?

I thoughs that ScrollView can help, but I have not found any properties for that.

Also I tried to use NumberPicker (that is not in google SDK, but available on my phone), but it show buttons with + and - and I can not convert it to a sliding up/down control.

Thanks.

Comment: I am unconvinced that either of these are in "default android", at least for my definition of "default android". Please upload screenshots that show the widgets in question. Also, `NumberPicker` was added to the SDK in Android 3.0.

Comment: I have found very similar control for selecting numbers (and not only numbers): http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/